# I am trying to redirect to another page after submitting a form on modal

Tags: javascript

I am using the below script to redirect to the page I want.

```
<script>   
     document
  .getElementById("register-form")
  .addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = "wallet.php";
      });
</script>
```

The problem is: if I remove the e.preventDefault(); the form gets submitted but does not redirect to the page, if I include it the form does not get submitted but redirects to the page wallet.php

Please help I would like to submit the form and redirect to wallet.php

Comment: After submitting form you can also redirect using PHP's header() function.

Comment: You cannot submit the form via a regular form submission (which opens another page) ***and*** redirect to yet another page at once. You'll have to submit the form *via AJAX* (and wait until that request finishes correctly) and *then* redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Submitting form with Ajax, using jQuery:

```
$("form").on('submit', function(e){
    $.post("form-submit.php", $(this).parent("form").serialize(),
        function(){
            window.location.href = "wallet.php";
        }
    );
    e.preventDefault();  
});
```

It might be easier to redirect it in form-submit.php using

```
header("location: wallet.php");
```

(replace `form-submit.php` by your form handler name.)

Comment: header("location: wallet.php"); works on a form that is not on the modal, the solution i need is for the form that is on modal, When i submit the form header("location: wallet.php"); is ignored.

Comment: okay, do you mean an iframe by "modal"? because using window.location.href from that might be a little more complicated ..